# C++ runtime decision which class method will be frequently called without condition killing performance

Tags: c++, optimization

In my numerical c++ project, I have a class that has two different private methods (MetA(), MetB()). Each of them is performing different, relatively simple. arithmetic operations in double precision. They are called by a public method MethP() of the same class.

```
class Integrator {
private:
  void MetA() { ... }
  void MetB() { ... }
public:
  void MethP() { can call either MetA or MetB }
```

Earlier in the program, before an object of this class is constructed, it is decided whether MetA() or MetB() will be used. Then, once the object is constructed, only one of the methods will be called, the other will not be called at all. MethP is mandatory and it has to be used.

The issue is that MethP() will be called really large number of times (10^9...10^11 or so).

Is there any elegant way to implement the selection of MetA or MetB inside MethP (or elsewhere inside the class)? I feel that a condition or switch inside MethP is not right as it negatively affect the performance. Is it better to make two subclasses and implement MetA and MetB as two different virtual version of one method called by MethP in the parent class? Is there any way to avoid an overhead of calling the virtual methods? Thanks.

I have tried a condition inside MethP.

Comment: Benchmark it.  An `if` statement doesn't cost much and the branch predictor might reduce that cost still further.  Also, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely

Comment: If you determine there's a measurable performance loss, one trick to experiment with is to make your implementation (which can itself be private) use a template internally, and you then specialize that template. The template parameterizes your operation (either `MetA` or `MetB`) using a functor or lambda. Your `Integrator` class then selects and instantiates the appropriate template specialization and `MethP` runs it. This essentially gives you code re-use and (probably) inlining without duplication or virtual methods.

Comment: Considering how often `MethP` runs, the branch predictor will have a success rate over 99.9%. `[[likely]]` is completely the wrong idea, because when it's wrong, it will be wrong in 100% of the iterations. The branch predictor is going to be wrong in a few iterations at most.

Comment: Is there really a noticeable performance impact once you enable your compilers optimizer? Have you profiled the generated code to determine that *this* is really the main cause of your performance issue? It might be, but I doubt it. Show us your analysis and proof.

Comment: Does `MetA()` or `MetB()` always called in the process' lifetime? I.e one execution calls only one method

Answer (score 1):

If applicable, the best branch prediction is no prediction. That's make the decision only once:

```
template<bool call_A>
void Integrator::MethP(){
     if (call_A)
         return MethA();
     else 
         return MethB();
};

/*...*/

auto run = []<bool call_A>(std::bool_constant<call_A>){
    /*put all the logic here*/
      x.MethP<call_A>();
    /*...*/
};
if (call_method_A())
    return run(std::bool_constant<true>);
else
    return run(std::bool_constant<false>);
```

This roughly duplicates binary size, but branches only once: the traditional trade between memory and speed.
Otherwise you will eventually involve the branch predictor.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use inheritance instead

```
// Base class
class Integrator {
public:
    virtual ~Integrator() {}

    // Pure virtual method to be implemented by the derived classes
    virtual void Met() = 0;
};

// Class for MetA
class IntegratorA : public Integrator {
public:
    void Met() override;
};

void IntegratorA::Met() {
    std::cout << "Called MetA\n";
}

// Class for MetB
class IntegratorB : public Integrator {
public:
    void Met() override;
};

void IntegratorB::Met() {
    std::cout << "Called MetB\n";
}

Integrator* integrator = needMetA ? new IntegratorA() : new IntegratorB();
integrator->Met();
```

Comment: But that just replaces one kind of branch with another kind

Comment: This would be nearly the same as `void MethP() { return needMetA ? MetA() : MetB(); }` except it also introduces a vtable lookup.

Comment: The OP already knows about this, and mentions that she or he wants to avoid virtual dispatch.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven the table lookup is fixed so it can be reliably predicted

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, it can be predicted, but a boolean branch predictor needs much less state, so CPU's are much better at those predictions.

Comment: @MSalters a vtable call is simply function pointer lookup so there's no prediction at all, just another level of indirection

Comment: Indirect branches are also predicted (otherwise the front-end would have to stall until the destination is known, which could take a while). For example, Intel CPUs probably use ITTAGE (they used to, and I haven't heard of them switching to something new, but I don't hear everything). Old CPUs used simpler mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

Consider branch prediction in the given problem: [Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor).

Secondly, I'm not sure if this is the whole class that you specified here, but since it doesn't have any internal state (members) and doesn't take any arguments in any of the methods maybe actually creation of the Integrator object is not needed at all and the MethA and MethB code can be just inlined in the parent class.

After all (in case non of the above is helpful), the "if" statement is just a short jump in the code, so there should be no fear in trying that.

Anyway, if this kind of performance issues bother you, the simplest would be to simply benchmark it and check all the options by yourself.

Comment: This is pretty much a long comment with a bit of general advice. Sometimes those make for decent answers when the answer is effectively, "Nope. Can't do that." But that's not the case here.

Comment: @Pat, thank you. Since the branch prediction happens at runtime rather than at compile time, this can actually be the solution I am looking for. I will benchmark and see. As for the state, the class has data members and an internal state. It needs to exist. I just skipped the details of the implementation to keep my post as simple as possible.